# Troubleshooting API timeout from Django+Celery in Docker Container

Tags: python, django, docker, containers, celery

I have a micro-services architecture of let say 9 services, each one running in its own container.

The services use a mix of technologies, but mainly Django, Celery (with a Redis Queue), a shared PostgreSQL database (in its own container), and some more specific services/libraries.

The micro-services talk to each other through REST API.

The problem is that, sometimes in a random way, some containers API doesn't respond anymore and get stuck. 
When I issue a `curl` request on their interface I get a timeout.

At that moment, all the other containers answer well.

There is two stucking containers. 
What I noticed is that both of the *blocking* containers use:

- Django
- django-rest-framework
- Celery
- django-celery
- An embedded Redis as a Celery broker
- An access to a PostgreSQL DB that stands in another container

I can't figure out how to troubleshoot the problem since no relevant information is visible in the Services or Docker logs.

*The problem is that these API's are stuck only at random moments. To make it work again, I need to stop the blocking container, and start it again.*

I was wondering if it could be a **python GIL problem**, but I don't know how to check this hypothesis...

Any idea about how to troubleshot this?

Comment: when using docker general practice is one daemon per container

Comment: I use indeed supervisord that in turn runs several daemon in foreground (nginx/gunicorn/celery/redis) in the same container.

Comment: and I am saying that defeats the whole purpose of using docker. Why don't you run all those things on the host OS directly?

Comment: For architectural and modularity needs. But I have lot of other services that run well using several daemon. I suspect the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: as you wish. But that's poor architecture. Using docker just because the marketing department thought the more $$ can be charged from the client by mentioning a trendy technology.

Comment: Totally agree with @e4c5, you're debugging pains stem directly from your misuse of containers. Try unpacking them into separate containers and keep them together with docker-compose. You'll have a much easier time then.

Comment: Indeed I have a full docker-compose setup, similar to most of those used in lot of projects found in github for instance. All as been working well after a certain point. The thing is that I don't know at which level I can troubleshoot the problem I met.

Answer (score 0):

You can shell into the running container and check things out. Is the celery process still running, etc...

`docker exec -ti my-container-name /bin/bash`

If you are using django, for example, you could go to your django directory and do `manage.py shell` and start poking around there.

I have a similar setup where I run multiple web services using django/celery/celerybeat/nginx/...

However, as a rule I run one process per container (kind of exception is django and gunicorn run in same container). I then share things by using `--volumes-from`.

For example, the gunicorn app writes to a .sock file, and the container has its own nginx config; the nginx container does a `--volumes-from` the django container to get this info. That way, I can use a stock nginx container for all of my web services.

Another handy thing for debugging is to log to stdout and use docker's log driver (splunk, logstash, etc.) for production, but have it log to the container when debugging. That way you can get a lot of information from 'docker logs' when you've got it under test. One of the great things about docker is you can take the exact code that is failing in production and run it under the microscope to debug it.

Comment: Thanks Ryan for your answer. 
*"However, as a rule I run one process per container"*: Is it not recommanded to run more than one process per container? Does this involves that things mess up?
My containers are used to run processes like this (inspired from Phusion Docker image)

`my_init---runsvdir-+-runsv
                   |-runsv---run---filebeat---9*[{filebeat}]
                   `-runsv---run---supervisord-+-gunicorn---gunicorn
                                               `-nginx---4*[nginx]`

Comment: In practice I just find it simpler to keep to one process per container. It makes things more modular and composable, easier to debug, easier to deploy (like you only need to deploy your django container if you have a code update, nginx etc. just need a restart), etc. I've seen other teams try for multiple processes per container -- when trying to dockerize an existing app -- and they usually run into problems.